# Return object key with minimum property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, ecmascript-6

I have an object with multiple keys (e.g. idOne, idTwo, idThree, idFour) ... each key contains an array of objects. I would like to **return and output the key with minimum price**. In this example, idThree contains the minimum price of id and therefore should output idThree. I have code that returns the minimum price found ... but my goal is to return key (idThree). Is there a simpler/cleaner way?

```
const object = {
   idOne: [{ price: 300 }],
   idTwo: [{ price: 200 }, { price: 100 }],
   idThree: [{ price: 90 }, { price: 100 }],
   idFour: [{ price: 99 }, { price: 210 }]
}
```

**Current Code**

```
const arrayOfMinValues = []
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)) {
  const minimumEntry = Math.min(...value.map(item => item.price))
  arrayOfMinValues.push(minimumEntry)
}

console.log('MIN VALUE IS: ', Math.min(...arrayOfMinValues)) // how can I return key?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested reduce calls to get an object with the minimum `key` and `value`, and destructure the `key`:

```js
const object = {"idOne":[{"price":300}],"idTwo":[{"price":200},{"price":100}],"idThree":[{"price":90},{"price":100}],"idFour":[{"price":99},{"price":210}]}

const { key } = Object.entries(object)
  .reduce((acc, [key, values]) =>
    values.reduce((r, { price }) => price < r.price ? { key, price } : r, acc)
  , { key: null, price: Infinity })

console.log(key)
```

Comment: Thanks! What is the purpose of: { key: null, price: Infinity } ?

Comment: Initial values to compare against in of the object doesn't have any properties (empty object).

Answer (score 2):

If you first turn the object into an array of entries, and turn each subarray into the single lowest price in the array, you can then `.reduce` to iterate over all of those lowest prices and pick out the entry with the lowest one:

```js
const object = {
   idOne: [{ price: 300 }],
   idTwo: [{ price: 200 }, { price: 100 }],
   idThree: [{ price: 90 }, { price: 100 }],
   idFour: [{ price: 99 }, { price: 210 }]
}

const minEntry = Object.entries(object)
  .map(([key, arr]) => [key, Math.min(...arr.map(obj => obj.price))])
  .reduce((a, b) => a[1] > b[1] ? b : a);
console.log('Min entry:', minEntry);
```

To access a property of an array, use `[index]` where `index` is the index you want to access:

```
const key = minEntry[0]
```

Comment: Thank you! What if I want minEntry to just be "idThree" or key? I don't care about price

Comment: Then access the key portion of the entry. An entry is just a key-value pair in the form of an array.

Comment: Er... you are confused about how to take a value from an array by index?

Comment: No lol, I was confused how it was reduced to include both key and min price ... was hoping to just reduce it down to just the key without having to reference an index ... ideally minEntry should be string with key

Comment: All you need to do is take the key from the entry array. You have to keep both the key and value (min price for that key) together when using `.reduce` for the logic to work. After that's done, extract the key from the minimum entry found.

Answer (score 1):

Another variation of reduce() using find()

```js
const object = {"idOne":[{"price":300}],"idTwo":[{"price":200},{"price":100}],"idThree":[{"price":90},{"price":100}],"idFour":[{"price":99},{"price":210}]}


const [key, lp] = Object.entries(object).reduce((a, [k, v])=>{
     const low = v.find(o => o.price < a[1]);    
     return low ? [k, low.price] : a;   
},[null,Infinity])

console.log(key, ' has low price of ',lp )
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple *approach* to use with steps:

1. Create `sumPrices()` function to get sum of prices.

```js
function sumPrices(arr){
    sum = 0;
    for(const price of arr){
        sum += price["price"]
    }
    return sum;
}
```

2. Create variable `keys` has all keys.
   Create two vars `minKey` the key of lowest prices.
   and `minSum` sum of lowest prices.

```
const keys = Object.keys(object);
let minKey = null,
    minSum = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
```

3. iterate over array keys
   get each sum of each inner array
   and compare `currentSum` with `minSum` if less than minimum.
   keep track the minSum with thier recpective key.

```js
for(const key of keys){
    const currentSum = sumPrices(object[key])
    if(currentSum <= minSum){
          minKey = key;
          minSum = currentSum;
    }
}
console.log(minKey);
```